# Searching through a String using Tilde (~) and search()

Tags: javascript

I was reading an article about Tilde operator in JavaScript. I saw an example that showed we can use ~ for searching through string as below :

```
var str = 'posterous';
if ( str.search('t') >= 0 ) {
// character t found
}
else{
// not found
}
```

With ~ :

```
var str = 'posterous';

if ( !~str.search('t') ) {
// character 't' not found branch
}
else{
// found branch
}
```

My question is that how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Joe Zim's blog explains what it is](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/)

> Tilde(~) is **a unary operator** that takes the expression to its right
>   performs this small algorithm on it (where N is the expression to the
>   right of the tilde): `-(N+1)`

All numbers except `0` are considered *truthy*

`String.indexOf` or `String.search` returns `-1` if not found and `~-1` is `0` which is *falsey*

Comment: You said "All numbers except 0 are truthy(That is, they evaluate to true)". But when we alert((-4==true)) it will alert false. So, why?

Comment: @AmirJalilifard it won't work. It is comparing a number and true, which will be casted to `1` so it will become `-4 == 1` which is false. They are *considered* truthy. Like `if(-4){alert("Success");}`

Comment: I got it. So all the numbers except 0 are considered as truthy. They just considered truthy not, true! Thanks!

Comment: @AmirJalilifard yup. That is what I meant :)